# Cache a Google Apps Provisioning API login object with Django

Tags: python, django, google-apps

I have a Django site that pulls up email groups from Google Apps using the provisioning API. I have something like:

```
import gdata.apps.groups.client

client = gdata.apps.groups.client.GroupsProvisioningClient(domain="example.com")
client.ClientLogin('email', 'password', source='apps')
```

The login takes a while, so I asynched the retrievals with ajax calls. It is the login call that takes up most of the time and it needs to be done for multiple views. Eg: one view renders the list of available groups and another view renders members of a selected group.

I'm wondering if there's a way in Django to kinda persist such a client object so that it would be available in multiple views?

Answer (score 0):

If you made the GroupsProvisioningClient instance a module level global, and have utility function to get it, like:

```
CLIENT = GroupsProvisioningClient(domain="example.com")
def get_gapps_client():
    if not CLIENT.is_authenticated() # made up function!
       CLIENT = CLIENT.ClientLogin('email', 'password', source='apps')
    return CLIENT
```